# iPhone app Rejection

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I recently submitted my app and Apple rejected it because I used: 'AppName iPhone Edition'

Which seemed to be correct from reading their terms and conditions, but they told me I cannot use iPhone in the name displayed on the device.

So, the question is, when I change the Product Name in the build settings, it asked me for a new provisioning profile.  Do I need to create a new provisioning profile, or can I just change the app name that appears on the device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change your app name and not need a new provisioning profile as long as you keep the same bundle ID.

Comment: ok, but where do I change the name.  I changed Product Name in the build settings and it wants a new provisioning profile.  Or, do I need to manually enter the bundle ID and make it the same?

Comment: You can change the name under the meta data section in iTunes connect. Are you trying to change the name in the provisioning portal?

Comment: The name that appears on the device is set in the info tab in xCode under "Bundle Display Name"  This is different than the product name and different from the name you specify on iTunes Connect,

Comment: I searched, but cannot find Bundle Display Name, can you please tell me where to find it?

Comment: Yes it is because the bundle display name is what appears under the icon on the home screen where as the app name is what appears in iTunes

Comment: you need to find your info.plist file and you can edit it directly. The raw name is "CFBundleDisplayName" or it will be called "Bundle display name"

Comment: Yes, Found it!!!  Thanks, forgot about the plist.  So I can change the bundle name which is the name that appears on the device, but iTunes Connect can stay the same.

Comment: I guess I'm assuming they rejected your app based on the name that appears in iTunes because "AppName iPhone Edition" can't fit as the bundle display name. If that is the case then you probably don't need to change the bundle display name directly and you can resubmit the meta data information. Did they say something like "meta information review failed". I don't remember the exact wording but many times you can just change that and resubmit without a new binary.

Comment: They told me this: "Thank you for your response. It would be appropriate to remove the "iPhone" from your app short name displayed on the device to comply with the Guidelines."  So I was trying to change the 'app short name displayed on the device'  without getting a new provisioning profile or changing things in iTunes Connect.  If I change the Bundle Name per above, then it cannot find a suitable iTines connect record. I do not know what to do to correct the problem.

Comment: oh ok then it does appear you need to change the bundle display name as we already mentioned and be sure to remove "iPhone" from the iTunes name as well if its there. Looks like you're all set to get this fixed

Comment: LOL, no I am not all set because if i go into iTunes connect and try to change the name it tells me the name is already used... that is because I have an iPad version already approved.

Comment: oh well what is your iPad name? Usually the iPhone version will be the name and the iPad version will be called the name + "HD" or something to denote iPhone. Apple just doesn't want the word iPhone in there so you'll have to be creative to differentiate it. Another option you could do is resubmit the iPad version with an appropriate name and once its approved change the iPhone name to the original

Comment: Yes, I understand and it makes sense... so, is there any way to change the iPad name, or do i have to re-submit it?  I am assuming I need to re-submit.  -:(

Comment: Unfortunately apple used to let you change the name on the fly but they do not any longer. You will need to resubmit the app to be able to change the name.

Answer (score 2):

By default,the Info.plist has this:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
```

Just change it to whatever you want and keep your product name unmodified.

You also need to change it yin iTunes Connect.

Comment: got it, but next question, I was not able to change the name in iTunes Connect because it told me my app name was already used.  What do I do??  I have two versions an iPad version and iPhone version.  it is not a universal app.  I have two targets, one for iPhone, the other for iPad.  I would like to use the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Provisioning profiles are tied to the app identifier by default (com.yourCompany.yourAppProductName).  So when you change the product name (in the build settings)  the identifier changes also.  You can manually specify an identifier code in the summary to avoid problems like this.

Also be sure that you are changing the "Bundle Display Name" in the info tab.  This name can be anything and does not require changing the product name or identifier.